# How to get the checked value of a radio button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

The code below is what I'm using in JavaScript to check to see what radio button has been selected. This is a compilation of several things I've seen on the internet that I've tried and have had no success. I've patterned this code after the example in [Using javascript to check if a radio button is selected and return a specific answer based on the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816186/using-javascript-to-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-and-return-a-specific-an). This code is still not working.

```
var userInput;
var shopMethod = document.getElementsByName('Shopping');

for (var a = 0; a < shopMethod.length; a++)
{
    If (shopMethod[a].checked)
    {
        userInput = shopMethod[a].value;
    }
}

If (userInput == "M")
{
    strShopping = "Mail Order Catalog";
}
If (userInput == "L")
{
    strShopping = "Local Computer Store";
}
If (userInput == "C")
{
    strShopping = "Computer Superstore";
}       
If (userInput == "I")
{
    strShopping = "Internet/World Wide Web";
}

<input type=radio name="Shopping" value="M"> Mail Order Catalog</br>
<input type=radio name="Shopping" value="L"> Local Computer Store</br>
<input type=radio name="Shopping" value="C"> Computer Superstore</br>
<input type=radio name="Shopping" value="I"> Internet/World Wide Web
```

I want the variable `strShopping` to equal what the user's section is so it can be sent to a database. Can anyone see where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (shopMethod[a].checked)
```

**i** instead of I. Your letter I in If is uppercase

**Update 1:**

I only want to suggest this to improve your code. Instead all the if statements you can do something like this:

```
var hasTable = {
    "M": "Mail Order Catalog",
    "L": "Local Computer Store",
    "C":"Computer Superstore",
    "I": "Internet/World Wide Web"
};

var strShopping  = hasTable[userInput];
```

Comment: PERFECT!! I guess that's what I get for fogetting case sensitivity matters between programming/scripting languages.

Answer (score -1):

Your radio buttons' html statements are missing the onclick() function.
There is no connection between the html declarations and the function you referred to, above to connect your html elements and your javascript statements

Comment: There doesn't need to be an `onclick()` within the radio buttons. They have names that, when the form is submitted, get sent to an external JavaScript that handles the input.

Comment: Agree. I missed that document.getElementsByName part of your code.